# @method_decorator with login_required and permission_required

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm using Class-based views where I would like to ensure that each view can be access by logged-in users and by one type of the users only (there are two groups of users - each group has different permissions).

I'm implementing this according to the docs with persmissions (I'm using Django 1.7.7) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class, however using two parameters raises an error " *method_decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)*" .

Hence - how to do it such that those two factors(login and permissions) will be verified in a class-based view?

```
class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'

    @method_decorator(login_required, permission_required('patient.session.can_add_patient'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PatientCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your case, `permission_required` will redirect to the login page for users that are not logged in, so you don't need to use `login_required` at all.

```
@method_decorator(permission_required('patient.session.can_add_patient')
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

If you really did need to use multiple decorators, then you can use a list in Django 1.9+

```
decorators = [other_decorator, permission_required('patient.session.can_add_patient')] 

class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'

    @method_decorator(decorators)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

You can also shorten the code by decorating the class itself:

```
@method_decorator(decorators, name="dispatch")
class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'
```

On Django 1.8 and earlier, you can't pass a list to `method_decorator` or decorate the class, so you have to stack the decorators

```
class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'

    @method_decorator(other_decorator)
    @method_decorator(permission_required('patient.session.can_add_patient'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

The decorators will process the request in the order they are passed to [`method_decorator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class). So for the examples above, `other_decorator` will run before `permission_required`.

Comment: Good idea! Thanks! :) Btw - how to show to a redirected user that we didn't had permissions to that view?

Comment: You'd be better to ask that as a separate question really. If you use the `raise_exception` parameter ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator)), then Django will return a 403 response. You could customize that as you wish (you'd probably have to handle users that aren't logged in).

Comment: @BarthesSimpson this was originally written for Django 1.7, when you couldn't pass a list to `method_decorator`. I've updated the answer for Django 1.9+.